# Apache doesn't detect ui-router state change

Tags: angularjs, apache, angular-ui-router, ui-sref, locationmatch

I am using `LocationMatch` Apache directive to apply some logic to an AngularJS app. To test, I have the regex cover just one state, http://my.ui.com/login

**Apache**

```
<LocationMatch "^/(login)(.*)">
    Redirect "/login" "/login2"
</LocationMatch>
```

This simple `Redirect` is used to check if the block has been triggered. When I got to the URL above directly (fake URL, sorry I can't share the real app), I can see the redirect working by observing the URL bar. However, if I navigate to this state using a `ui-sref` button, the LocationMatch block is never triggered. Here is the relevant AngularJS code, I am using the ui-router library:

**UI State**

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
});
```

**Button (clicking doesn't trigger Apache)**

```
<button class="md-button" ui-sref="login">Login</button>
```

I'm guessing because the AngularJS app is loaded all at once, there is no disk read made when a stateChange occurs. Does anyone know of a better way for Apache to detect state changes in an AngularJS app?

Comment: `html5mode` is enabled?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, with `FalbackResource index.html` in my `<Directory>` block

Comment: @PankajParkar are you aware of any way to dynamically load files from disk (not web server) in AngularJS? That may be a way to trigger Apache...`ng-include` does not seem to work here

Comment: file protocol would not work with $http/ajax call.. so It would not work